# Change one menu item size in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I've bottom menu bar that has 4 items from which one has to look differently (not depending on which item is selected/not). One item has to have bigger icon size.

Currently I'm styling my elements like this:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="itemIconTint">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="itemIconSize">26dp</item>
</style>
```

However, `itemIconSize` is affecting all menu items and not one specific. How to change icon size for specific menu item?